# How to properly use USB sticks on Linux and Windows machines?

Tags: usb-storage

I've been a Linux user for about a year (Fedora 20) and have had a persistent problem with USB sticks (USB from now on for short) since then. I use my USB in both Linux and Windows machines, and my problem is that when I store some file or folder in my USB from my Linux machine then I'm unable to locate this file when using the USB from a Windows machine; sometimes a direct access to a folder stored from the Linux machine does appear when I use the USB in the Windows machine but not the folder itself. This problem occurs occasionally, not permanently, so I can, sometimes, transfer files between OSs via USB with no trouble; but I don't understand why or when the problem occurs.

I would like to know how can I fix this problem.

Comment: Is it possible that you've removed the stick without unmounting it first, so that a pending write couldn't be completed?

Comment: @MartinvonWittich No, it's not possible. I'm always careful to remove the USB stick only after it has been unmounted.

Comment: Which filesystem are you using?

Comment: @Graeme Fat32 in the USB stick and Ext4 in my Linux machine.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'a direct access to a folder stored from the Linux machine does appear when I use the USB in the Windows machine but not the folder itself?' What is a 'direct access?'

Comment: @Graeme When I use the USB in the Windows machine and look at the 'file type' column it says 'Direct Access'. When I click it a new window opens with the contents of the folder.

Comment: I've seen the exact same problem on network shares too between Windows and Linux.  I'll write a file from one OS and the other won't see it sometimes.

Comment: It sounds like the file is always there, and that your problem is that sometimes Windows shows it in some weird way. You need a Windows expert, not a Linux expert.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Windows's “Direct Access” feature, whatever that is.

Comment: Agree w/ Gilles: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectAccess -> this is a windows related issue.